# sonataadmin as both frontend and backend for symfony 2 project

Tags: symfony

I used sonataadmin and really like some features, like creating an entity and its related entity in the same page. I want to use it for frontend user also. Is it possable to use sonamaadmin for both backend and frontend users? Or is there another bundle allowing me to create an entity and its related entity in the same page?

Answer (score 0):

Those are just form types, provided by the SonataAdminBundle. You can use them in any form.

You probably looking for the `sonata_type_model` or `sonata_type_collection`. See [the documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/reference/form_types.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use Sonata Admin in both, although will be like only having a backend and made the correct security configuration for two kind of users. About entity and its related entities in the same page, that has nothing to do with Sonata, this can be achieved with symfony simple and embed forms.